# Unable to align spinner and Button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-spinner

Im using the following code to align a Spinner then a edittext and then a button. The following code is an activity that's defined as dialog.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/selector"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/action"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></Spinner>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/remark"
        style="@style/textbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/decide"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/decide"
        android:layout_below="@+id/selector"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/decide"
        style="@style/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/remark"
        android:text="Submit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

1. I want the spinner to take the entire space in terms of width. Below spinner will be an edittext
2. I want the button to occupy the bottom left.

But my code doesnt make the spinner to occupy the entire screen. 
using `android:gravity="left"` makes the button text to appear at the top left corner instead of making the button itself to appear at the left.

How can I sort this out? 
[image]

Above one is my screen shot.As you could see, the spinner is not occupying the entire screen width as that of textbox. The button has to be small and it should appear at left corner.but its not happening

following is btn.xml that i add to button

```
<style name="btn" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_states</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10.0dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">50.0dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">10.0dip</item>
    </style>
```

Following is my style for textbox

```
<style name="textbox" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:textSize">18.0dip</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittext_states</item>
        <item name="android:padding">8.0dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">10.0dip</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/selector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip"
    android:entries="@array/action" >
</Spinner>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/remark"
    style="@style/textbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/selector" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/decide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/remark"
    android:background="@color/purple"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Done" />
```

Comment: still the same problem is persisting.

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: all views are getting aligned to the bottom. Button appears so small

Comment: so u want to button width in full size..??or make sure your parentview width you set 300 dp it is ok..?

Comment: or provide some rough design u want to do

Comment: first of all in your spinner you use `android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"` remove this.

Comment: or as per your xml and screenshot does not match...so please sure screenshot for your xml?

Comment: so finally what u want for Button..?

Comment: i have updated it. The button should be toward the left and it should not occupy the entire screen.

Comment: the spinner should be occupying the entire screen width like the way editText is

Comment: for button set width `"match_parent"`

Comment: i tried it but i dont want my button to occupy the entire screen width

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code changed from **RelativeLayout to LinearLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_lay1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/selector"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_lay2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/remark"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EditTxt" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_lay3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decide"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:background="@color/purple"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Done" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```